# replace caret png by fontawesome caret in css file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, png, font-awesome

I would like to replace the background image in my menu with a string that uses a FontAwesome character. It is a ready-made menu, a module in Joomla.

It looks like this:

[image: menu]

Here is the CSS:

```
.responsiveMenuTheme5m.isMobile > li.deeper > span {
    background-image: url("../images/downArrow.png") !important;
    background-position: right 57px !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}
```

So the menu coder provided an image called downArrow.png. Which is basically a caret-down. I would like to replace this with FontAwesome  `<span class="fa fa-caret-down"> </span>`. I've got a Twitter Bootstrap 3 template and I've got FontAwesome installed, so I thought this should be a possibility, even without tinkering with the menu code, but only with css.

Can anyone help me do it?

Comment: Have you tried something ?? Try to link the fontawesome css and include the font folder then with a pseudo-element include the icon. Try

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.responsiveMenuTheme5m.isMobile > li.deeper > span{
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.responsiveMenuTheme5m.isMobile > li.deeper > span:before {
  content: "\f0d7";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able this by changing css of span element. If everything is ok and font awesome is imported correctly by adding:

`.responsiveMenuTheme5m.isMobile > li.deeper > span:before {
    content: "\f0d7";
}`

your font will appear.

You can check out this code `http://fontawesome.io/icon/caret-down/`

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this one:

```
.responsiveMenuTheme5m.isMobile > li.deeper > span {
    background-position: right 57px !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
}
```

Replace the caret with the following code:

```
<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
```

You might have to use the <span> as an option, like so:

```
<span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span>
```

You might have to play with the left caret distance by changing the values found in the background-position.